# REGEX find AWS lambda REPORT parameters

Tags: python, regex

I intend to extract each parameters into variables from cloudwatch stream log using lambda python. But keep getting None value.

```
import re

s = "2021-02-22T01:40:15.439Z REPORT RequestId: 2b4b3f67-xxxx-xxxx-8563-14cd1b188e5e Duration: 2.36 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 85 MB  Init Duration: 896.04 ms"

result = re.search(r"RequestId: ([\s.]+).*Duration: ([\s.]+)",s)

print(result)
```

Raw log stream:

```
2021-02-22T01:40:15.439Z REPORT RequestId: 2b4b3f67-xxxx-xxxx-8563-14cd1b188e5e Duration: 2.36 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 85 MB  Init Duration: 896.04 ms
```

Expected result getting like this:

```
result.group(1) = "2b4b3f67-xxxx-xxxx-8563-14cd1b188e5e"
result.group(2) = 2.36
```

Comment: Good job on the question, btw, you share input, what you tried and expected output.  Makes it easy for me to help you.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `\s` for whitespace, when you mean `\S` for non-whitespace.  With regular expressions I often find it useful to be "minimal" and match on separators:

```
 result = re.search(r"RequestId: ([^ ]+) Duration: ([^ ]+)", s)
```

If it was me, I would extract each key with a separate regex so you don't depend on the order of parameters, and I would include the unit in the value for the duration and convert it unit-less value in ms in a separate function (not shown):

```
 request_id = re.search(r'RequestId: ([^ ]+)', s).group(1)
 duration = re.search(r'Duration: ([^ ]+ [^ ]+)', s).group(1)
 ...
```

I would observe that the only difference is the variable name, parameter key `k` and parameter value `v`, so I would write a meta-function `parameter` to generate a function for each parameter:

```
 def parameter(k, v):
     return lambda s: re.search(r'' + k + ': ' + v, s).group(1)

 RequestId = parameter('RequestId', '([^ ]+)')
 Duration = parameter('Duration', '([^ ]+ [^ ]+)')
 ...

 print(RequestId(s))
```

Comment: clean and works! what if i want to extract every parameters, and retrieve from result.group? will this works? re.search(r"RequestId: ([^ ]+) Duration: ([^ ]+) Billed Duration: ([^ ]+) Init Duration: ([^ ]+)", s)

Comment: You have to account for the extra spaces (or tab).  You could use \s+ instead of just space: "RequestId: ([^ ]+)\s+".  The other issue is the units for the duration, my suggestion would be to include those in the match so `Duration: ([^ ]+ [^ ]+)`.

Comment: Also, if it was me, I would extract each value with a separate regex so you don't depend on order of the keys within the string.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the details for you, I think this will be necessary when you want to check each cluster.

```
regex = r"RequestId[:](\s*)((\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+))(\s*)Duration[:](\s*)((\d).(\d+))"
```

I think that's enough for you to upgrade.
Result:

https://regex101.com/r/uvDGWY/1

Image Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use 4 capture groups to get all parts and make the match a bit more specific per group.

```
\bRequestId:\s+(\w+(?:-\w+)+)\s+Duration:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s.*?\bBilled\s+Duration:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s.*?\bInit Duration:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

The pattern matches

- `\bRequestId:\s+(\w+(?:-\w+)+)\s+` Match *RequestId* and capture in **group 1** matching word characters with a `-` in between
- `Duration:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s.*?` Match *Duration* and capture in **group 2** a number with optional decimal part followed by matching as least as possible chars
- `\bBilled\s+Duration:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s.*?` Match *Billed Duration* and capture in **group 3** a number with optional decimal part followed by matching as least as possible chars
- `\bInit Duration:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b` Match *Init Duration* and capture in **group 4** a number with optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NGEVOC/1)